# Checking for Market Holidays in Pine

Tags: pine-script

Hey I'm working on the hourly time frame and am looking back 5 days based on some logic I've built.  Is there a quick way to check back the last 5 bars on a daily chart to see if there any holidays in the past week.  My indicator uses 5 days of data so just want to see if there is a easy way to check for this.  I have the time for 5 days back on the hourly, so was thinking of comparing the 5th bar back on the daily chart to this, and if they are different then I would use the time on the open of the daily bar 5 bars back.

I'm assuming something to do with multi-time frame but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0):

To check the last 5 days it's easy
The holidays aren't available in pinescript, so you'll have to create constant variables with the timestamp of each holiday

```
LAST_5DAYS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 5
window = timenow - time < LAST_5DAYS

holiday1 = timestamp(...)
holiday2 = timestamp(...)

if window

    if holiday1 or holiday2
```